# hibernate.cfg.xml file error

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hql

I have a problem concerning hibernate.cfg.xml file, every time I try to run HQL Query for any table from my database this list of error appears.

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2551)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2537)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2367)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:939)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1260)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:91)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1034)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:194)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:791)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:866)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1186)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3387)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3431)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80)
    ... 15 more
```

Connection with database is working properly, I am using Oracle database, NetBeans 8.0.2 and Hibernate 4.3.1.

File hibernate.cfg.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">nemanja</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">nemanja</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
    <mapping resource="model/Racun.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Stavkatransakcije.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Transakcija.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Nalog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Klijent.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Objekatkupovine.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Try to print the query by enabling show_sql=true. It seems your query is wrong.

Comment: I am using the easiest query with FROM clause, I just wanted to test how the HQL is working and that is the problem, I can't make it work anyhow

Comment: Did you try the show_sql thing suggested by Nambari? What does the query looks like? Can you please paste the query? The error you are getting is saying that there is something wrong with your query.

Comment: model/Racun.hbm.xml is complete path of your class?